# getting the operations (a.k.a methods or functions) in a soap web service from the wsdl with .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap, asp.net-core, wsdl

I need a way to find the operations in a SOAP web service using the WSDL of the web service.

Comment: While this may be useful information, the solution should not go into the _question_, rather you should express the problem in the question and put the solution into an _answer_.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a public wsdl url such as http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl or https://www.lb.lt/webservices/ExchangeRates/ExchangeRates.asmx?WSDL for testing. The solution is as follows: 1) get the contents of the wsdl url. 2) Parse the wsdl xml for the operations. The code is as follows.

```
public string[] GetOperations(string wsdlURL)
{

    //string httpResponseMessage;
    List<string> sList = new List<string>();
    string[] s = { };
    string result = GetWSDLContent(wsdlURL);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(result);

    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("wsdl", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
    var nl = doc.SelectNodes("//wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation", nsmgr);
    for (var i=0; i<nl.Count; i++ ) 
    {
        sList.Add(nl[i].Attributes["name"].Value.ToString());
    }
    s = sList.ToArray();
    return s;
}
public string GetWSDLContent(string wsdlURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wsdlURL);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();
    return result;
}
```